# My service failed to uninstall

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-services

I recently tried to change the display name of my windows service, but apparantly I messed up. An old version fails to uninstall completely and I cannot install a new version of the windows service. This is the error generated from running installutil /i myService:

```
An exception occurred during the uninstallation of the System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller installer.
System.InvalidOperationException: The event log source '7 Ac Service' cannot be deleted, because it's equal to the log name.
An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete.
```

So the event log source is equal to the log name. What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353736/cannot-uninstall-a-windows-service-cannot-be-deleted-because-its-equal-to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out myself. [This post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/delete-custom-event-log-source-t519883.html) helped. So there are basically 3 places in the registry in the same name as the windows service. So I tried first to write a console application to remove the eventlog:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Delete("7 Ac Service");
```

It took care of 2 of them. I removed the last one manually using regedit. Then my windows service installed without problems.